# Mocking a return value which is an object

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

I'd like to write some tests for the following code:

```
def person_name_length(id):
    person = get_person(id)
    return len(person.first_name)
```

How can I mock out `get_person(id)` method so that it returns an object which has a value for `first_name` property?

In code:

```
@patch('get_person')
def test_person_name_length(self, get_person_mock):
    get_person_mock.return_value = # what goes here??? calling .first_name on it should return 'Bob'
    self.assertEqual(person_name_length(1), 3)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you should need to do something like this

```
class MockPerson(object):
    first_name = 'Bob'


@patch('get_person')
def test_person_name_length(self, get_person_mock):
    get_person_mock.return_value = MockPerson()
    self.assertEqual(person_name_length(1), 3)
```

Comment: Can you explain how `@patch('get_person')` connects to `get_person_mock`? Each patch decorator maps to args in the test method? So if you wanted to patch another method you'd add `@patch('other_method')` under `@patch('get_person')` and add another arg `self, get_person_mock, other_method_mock`?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to create a one-off object for this.  This is easier:

```
@patch('get_person')
def test_person_name_length(self, get_person_mock):
    get_person_mock.return_value = mock.Mock(first_name='Bob')
    self.assertEqual(person_name_length(1), 3)
```